# github code search api returns html instead of json

Tags: python, api, github, python-requests, github-api

I want to get some data from github API through python:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Awesome-Octocat-App', 'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.preview+json'}
link = "https://github.com/search?q=chembl+created:>=2000"
r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
```

and it looks like everything went fine:

```
r.ok
>>> True
```

So I would expect to have json in response:

```
r.json()
```

But this throws an exception:

```
JSONDecodeError: No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

Unfortunately what I have is html:

```
r.content

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# githubog: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/githubog#">
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
...
```

This html contains all repositories I'm looking for but I need json not html. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [actual API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) to get JSON content. `http://github.com/search` is the regular HTML frontend. You probably wanted to [search for repositories](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories):

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Awesome-Octocat-App', 'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.preview+json'}
link = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories"
query = {'q': 'chembl created:>=2000'}
r = requests.get(link, headers=headers, params=query)
```

This gives me:

```
>>> r = requests.get(link, headers=headers, params=query)
>>> r.ok
True
>>> r.json().keys()
[u'total_count', u'items']
>>> r.json()['total_count']
17
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the URL:

`https://github.com/search?q=chembl+created:>=2000`

You should be using the URL:

`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=chembl+created:>=2000`.

Here is the documentation:

http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories